How can I solve my equation with the best numerical precision?
For the intersection between a ray:
$$
[x,y,z] = [x_0,y_0,z_0] + t*[dir_x,dir_y,dir_z] 
$$
with a plane:
$$
z = ax + by + c
$$
I have found
$$
t = \frac{ax_0 + by_0 + c - z_0}{dir_z - adir_x - bdir_y}
$$
$[dir_x,dir_y,dir_z]$ is an unit vector where $dir_x$ and $dir_y$ are almost zero and the plane is almost horizontal.
When implementing this is there some care I have to take besides checking that the denominator is not zero in order to achieve the best numerical results?
I notice that the terms $adir_x$ and $bdir_y$ both consist of a product of two near zero numbers.
I am using python/numpy/scipy.


When implementing this is there some care I have to take besides checking that the denominator is not zero in order to achieve the best numerical results?

No. The naive algorithm (compute the numerator as a scalar product, the denominator, and then divide) is already backward stable. This is easy to prove by modifying the standard backward stability proofs for scalar products (e.g., Sec. 3.1 of Higham's Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms).
In layman terms, that algorithm is already as good as it can get, given the unavoidable error that is due to uncertainty and machine approximation errors in your data. Even if you took the additional performance hit to convert all inputs from double (float64) to 100-digit precision, perform all computations with 100 digits of accuracy, and then convert back to double, it wouldn't be any more accurate than your current algorithm.
The problem itself will be ill-conditioned for some choices of the data, but there is nothing you can do about that (apart from switching to a different representation of your data).

The problem is inherently ill-posed if you are looking to compute the intersection point of two near-parallel lines or planes. This is inherent in the problem, not in the computation as a small perturbation in the inputs (the coefficients of the line and the plane) results in large changes in the output (the intersection point) even if you use exact arithmetic.
Of course, if you use computer arithmetic with finite precision, you aggravate the issue. But that's unavoidable and one of the questions worth asking is how exactly you know the data anyway. If you can only measure the coefficients of the line and plane to 4 digits of accuracy, it does not matter than you can only use 16 digits in computer arithmetic -- the dominant error sources is the measurement uncertainty.

I suppose you are using that for a ray-tracer? If this is so then you can very elegantly handle this through INFs and NaNs (using epsilons instead results in pop in and out artifacts). It's also nicer if you write this in vector notation because then this generalizes to $n$ dimensions. Let $\vec{n}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be the normal of your hyperplane, and let $c = \vec{n}\cdot \vec{q}$, where $\vec{q}$ is an arbitrary point on the hyperplane. Then the hyperplane equation is given as $$\vec{n}\cdot (\vec{p}-\vec{q}) = 0 \iff \vec{n}\cdot \vec{p} = \vec{n}\cdot \vec{q} = c.$$
Plug in $\vec{p} = \vec{r}(t) = \vec{o} + t\vec{d}$ in the above and solve for $t$:
\begin{align}
\vec{n}\cdot \vec{p} &= c \\
\vec{n} \cdot (\vec{o} + t\vec{d}) &= c \\
\vec{n}\cdot \vec{o} + t\vec{n}\cdot \vec{d} &= c \\
t &= \frac{c-\vec{n}\cdot\vec{o}}{\vec{n}\cdot\vec{d}}.
\end{align}
If $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{d}=0$ in code you can either get a negative infinity, positive infinity, or not a number. At least in C++ all of those would fail the following check that you may implement for the ray: 0< t && t<INF. So at the end of the day you can use something like:
float intersect_ray_hyperplane(vecn o, vecn d, vecn n, float c)
{
float t = (c - dot(n,o))/dot(n,d);
if (0.0f<t && t<INF)
    return t;
else
    return -1.0f;
}

If the result is negative you can treat this as a no intersection. Otherwise t gives you the desired result up to machine precision. You can ignore the case $t=0$ since this is a set of measure zero, and you could just take your ray to be from $(0,\infty)$.
In ray-tracing (at least for rendering applications as opposed to e.g. lens tracing) the end result is an image. The denominator becomes close to zero when the ray direction and the hyperplane normal become closer to perpendicular (i.e. the ray and plane are close to parallel). This doesn't matter too much though as such intersections are naturally far away and thus do not show up in a meaningful way in the image (it's a sub-pixel detail usually).
What should be avoided is a check like this:
float intersect_ray_hyperplane(vecn o, vecn d, vecn n, float c)
{
float t = (c - dot(n,o))/dot(n,d);
if (fabs(dot(n,d)) >= epsilon && t>=0.0f)
    return t;
else
    return -1.0;
}

The latter causes the hyperplane "popping into existence" (or out of existence) at specific angles. That is $|\vec{n}\cdot \vec{d}|\geq \epsilon$ is a poor check because it relies on an arbitrary $\epsilon$ and checks only the denominator, when it is the ratio that matters. Surprisingly you will find the above type of code in a lot of places (and I think even books and papers on rendering). Also the negative of the checks should be avoided
if (t<=0.0 || t == INF) 
   return -1.0;
else
    return t;

since NaNs fail all checks except isnan (they even fail x==x checks), and you would get a supposed intersection.
Another trick used in rendering (to avoid shadow acne) is that when you intersect an object you offset its intersection by an epsilon along the normal (so you don't end up under the surface). The epsilon should generally be scene dependent however. In your case if there is an intersection you can do $\vec{p} = \vec{o} + t\vec{d} + \epsilon \vec{n}$, where $t$ is the computed intersection parameter. Such issues are much more prominent for spheres $\|\vec{p}-\vec{c}\|^2 = R^2$ especially if you make their radius too large. There you can improve both the intersection routine (since it relies on solving for the roots of a quadratic) and for the aforementioned offset (I remember there was a chapter on that in the ray-tracing gems book).

(+1) I am not familiar with ray tracing. How important is it that the dot products are being computed as accurately as possible, e.g. through the use of fused multiply-add (FMA) operations (or possibly even more expensive techniques)? Shewchuk's 1996 paper "Robust Adaptive Floating-Point Geometric Primitives" made me aware that high accuracy is important in other related application areas.

@njuffa I suppose it depends on the dimension. If $n$ is large and you can accumulate a lot of round off from addition then you may even use Kahan's summation algorithm. In 3D probably not that much. In ray-tracing it's the visual result that mostly matters, so the issue arises when people do checks like if (fabs(dot(n,d))<epsilon) and return no intersection there. The latter causes pop in and pop out at specific angles since it looks only at the denominator, and it's really the ratio that matters. Infs and nans are better, but they don't magically  spare you from catastrophic cancelation.

I think that you can have issues if you add two really small or really big numbers. This is due to how they are represented numerically that gives rise to round off errors. One way to avoid this could be to factorize your really small numbers, do the computation and then multiply back. For example, instead of adding $a.10^{23}$ and $b.10^{24}$ you can do $a+10b$ and then multiply back by $10^{23}$. In your case, you could factorize the denominator before doing the division.
